# Homomorphisms from $S_{5}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ , what does it mean the ID subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I'm trying to find the number of homomorphisms from $S_{5}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ , meaning : 
$S_{5}$ $\longrightarrow$ $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

I'm using the 1st Isomorphism theorem .
$G/Ker(f)≅Im(f)$

So , we can have the following subgroups for Ker :

1. Id
2. $A_{5}$
3. $S_{5}$

For the first : $120/1≅Im(f)=120$ but by Lagrange theorem $|Im(f)|  | |\mathbb{Z}_{12}| $ , but 120 doesn't divide 12 , then this can't be .

Question : what does it mean the ID subgroup ? why its size is 1 ?

Regards

Comment: It means the subgroup consisting of just the neutral element in the group (also known as the identity element).

Comment: Please forgive me for asking (if my question is a little bit silly) : when we ask for the Identity subgroup of a symmetric group , does  it mean to a group with only one element ?

Comment: @ron - Yes.  Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what is meant by "the ID subgroup" (which is terrible notation, by the way) is the identity subgroup, ie $\{e\}$, where $e$ represents the identity element of $S_5$.

In general, if $G$ is any group with identity element $e_G$, then $\{e_G\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: JackManey : So, what is the the ID group of $S_{5}$ ? how much are there ? only one subgroup of the Identity ?

Comment: @ron - As I said, the identity group of $S_5$ consists of one element--namely the identity element of $S_5$.  Every group has a (necessarily unique) identity element.  The singleton set consisting of this element forms a normal subgroup of the given group.

Comment: @ron You really need to spend time with the definition of what a group is, what a subgroup is! Please go over these definitions to see for yourself that the identity subgroup is necessarily unique and is trivially a normal subgroup of a group. Further, understand that this is a _terrible_ notation. A nice way of calling this subgroup is just with $1$.

Comment: Understood . thanks .

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I am not sure what your question that comes under the title "Question" is. Let me try my best at it:

- The "ID" subgroup you seem to be interested in is called the identity subgroup, which for an abstract group $G$ is the singleton set $I=\{e_G\}$ where $e_G$ is the identity element of $G$. It is routine to check that $I$ is actually a subgroup of $G$.

For example, in $S_5$, $Id_{S_5}=(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)$ is the identity permutation which fixes all the five symbols whose group of permutations in $S_5$.

---

Your approach is right, but you fail to observe that, if $a \mid b$, then $a \le b$. This will get you out of those unnecessary contradictions.

---

Let $f$ be a homomorphism from $S_5$ to $\Bbb Z_{12}$. Then, you have following restrictions on $f$:

- The first isomorphism theorem, together with Lagrange's theorem tells you that, $$|S_5/\operatorname {Ker} f|~~ \mbox{$=$} ~~|\operatorname{Im} f| ~~~\mbox{divides}~~ |\Bbb Z_{12}|$$

> So, for knowing the cardinality of $\operatorname{Ker} f$,  notice that you  need to find all those $x$ such that $$\dfrac{120}{x} \mid 12$$ Firstly, this in particular means that, $\dfrac {120} x \le 12$. So, you have that, $x \ge 10$.

As you know that only normal subgroups in $S_5$ are $1=\{\operatorname{Id}_{S_5}\}, A_5$ and $S_5$, you are forced to conclude that $\operatorname{Ker} f \in \{A_5, S_5\}$.

So,...

Comment: Actually, $\vert G/ker f \vert = \vert Im f \vert$ since $G/ker f \cong Im f$.

Comment: Thank You for the pointer. I am sorry.

Comment: Oh, no worries.  :)